# Definite integral of ln(x) from 1 to a as the limit of a Riemann sum

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, riemann-sum, geometric-series, telescopic-series

For $a > 1$ determine the definite integral

$$
\int_1^a ln(x)
$$

as the limit of a Riemann sum. Hint: Use the partitioning $P_N = (x_0, x_1, …, x_N)$ with:

$$
1 = x_0 < x_1 < … < x_N = a \quad \text{and} \quad x_k = a^{\frac{k}{N}} \quad k = (0, 1, 2, …, N)
$$

and make use of geometric and telescoping series.

My approach is to form a lower (or upper) Riemann sum and then taking the limit with $N \rightarrow \infty$. So far I have this:

$$
\begin{align*}
S_{lower} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \inf f([x_k, x_{k+1}]) \cdot (x_{k+1} - x_k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f(x_k) \cdot (a^{\frac{k+1}{N}} - a^{\frac{k}{N}}) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} ln(a^{\frac{k}{N}}) \cdot (a^{\frac{k}{N} + \frac{1}{N}} - a^{\frac{k}{N}}) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{k}{N} \cdot ln(a) \cdot a^{\frac{k}{N}} (a^{\frac{1}{N}} - 1) \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (a^{\frac{1}{N}} - 1)}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} k \cdot (a^{\frac{1}{N}})^k \qquad \text{define } \quad q := a^{\frac{1}{N}} \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (q - 1)}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} k \cdot q^k \qquad \text{apply formula for partial sum of geometric series} \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (q - 1)}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} q \cdot \frac{d}{dq} q^k \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (q - 1)}{N} \cdot q \cdot \frac{d}{dq} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} q^k \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (q - 1)}{N} \cdot q \cdot \frac{d}{dq} \frac{1 - q^N}{1 - q} \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (q - 1)}{N} \cdot \frac{(N+1)q^{N+1} - Nq^N - q}{(1-q)^2} \qquad \text{resubstitute q} \\
&= \frac{ln(a) (a^{\frac{1}{N}} - 1)}{N} \cdot \frac{(N+1)(a^{\frac{1}{N}}) ^{N+1} - N (a^{\frac{1}{N}})^N - a^{\frac{1}{N}}}{(1-a^{\frac{1}{N}})^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Not really sure where to go from there. Obviously if I take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$ now I would have some zeroes in bad places. I believe I‘m starting off right but taking a wrong turn somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The $q-1$ cancels with one of the $1-q$ terms, yielding $-1.$

Comment: Note that $q^N=a$ and $q^{N+1}=qa.$

Comment: So the expression becomes: $$\frac{\ln a}{N}\frac{(N+1)aq - Na - q}{q-1}=\frac{\ln a}N\frac{Na(q-1)+q(a-1)}{q-1}$$